# Appium server GUI returned error "No route found for /session" & Appium inspector "Failed to create session. The requested resource could not be found

Tags: appium, mobile-automation, ios, mac

Error occur while launching the application using appium server gui with following
Environment :

- Appium server GUI[1.22.3]
- Appium inspector [2022.5.4]
- Capability set as follows :

```
{
  "appium:automationName": "XCUITest",
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "appium:deviceName": "iPhone 12 Pro",
  "appium:bundleId": "<app_bundleId>",
  "appium:app": "<local_path>"
}
```

**Observed error** on Appium server GUI :

```
[HTTP] No route found for /session
[HTTP] <-- POST /session 404 20 ms - 211
```

**Observed error** on Appium Inspector :

> Failed to create session. The requested resource could not be found,
> or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported
> by the mapped resource

Any possible work around or solution to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working tweek :

- In, Appium inspector just add `/wd/hub` under field Remote Path
  [image]
- Check it will start working now